# python dictionary to csv where each key is in seperate row and value in separate columns

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

I am having trouble trying to output my dictionary to CSV file.  I have a Dictionary that contains as keys time dates and as values, companies pertaining to those dates which are in string format.  I tried looking through the website for identical question, but it doesn't really help my case.  I tried the following code and managed to get the key in first row, values in second column but thats not what i want.

```
import csv
with open('dict1.csv','w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
    for key,values in sorted(a.items()):
        w.writerow([key,values])
```

But this gives me a CSV file in following format:

```
2009/01/02  ['AA' 'BB' 'AAPL'] etc
2009/01/03  ['AA' 'CC' 'DD' 'FF']
```

Hence I only have two columns.  But I want:

```
2009/01/02  'AA' 'BB' 'AAPL'
2009/01/02  'AA' 'CC' 'DD'  'FF'
```

in 4 separate columns for first row and 5 for the second row respectively.
I even tried

```
for dates in sorted(a):
    w.writerow([date] + my_dict[date] )
```

But this gives me error saying unsupported operand types for + 'timestamp' and 'str'.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Try converting the timestamp object into a string before appending it to a string. The date you're seeing on the left is probably not a string.

Comment: that didn't help.  converting to strings puts all the keys as separate columns for some reason which i want all my keys to be in the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is putting the key (the date) in the key variable, and the values, as a *list* in values. So values will indeed contain something like ['AA' 'BB' 'AAPL'].

```
for key,values in sorted(a.items()):
```

Next, you're telling writerow "write a row with two elements: the first is the key, the second is whatever is in values" (which is a list so it's just converted to a string representation and output like that).

```
    w.writerow([key,values])
```

so [key, values] looks like this:

```
[2009/01/02, ['AA','BB','AAPL']]
 ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 the key     this whole thing
             is the single value
```

What you'd want, I think, is to create a single list containing the key and strings, not one containing the key and a list of strings. You could extend a list with the extra values like so:

```
    the_row = [key]  # Create the initial row with just key
    the_row.extend(values)  # Add the values, one by one, to the row
    w.writerow(the_row)  # Write the full row
```

list.extend(L) does: Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list.

Comment: Apologies! extend() does not return the extended list, but modifies it in place. I'll fix the example in a second.

Answer (score 1):

Am sorry if I read this wrong, but are you using python pandas?

> " I have a Dictionary that contains as keys pandas time dates and as values, >companies pertaining to those dates which are in string format."

in that case something like this might work

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
df = df.transpose()
df.to_csv('dict1.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

the to_csv method be default uses ',' as a delimiter which you can change if needed.

Comment: no sorry.  the dates are in datetime object.  Not pandas.  I will change my wording.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put something like this:

```
for key,values in sorted(a.items()):
    w.writerow(str(key) + "," + ","join(values))
```

`",".join(values)` will split the list of values into a string delimited by commas. I'm assuming you want commas separating your columns because you are writing a csv file, even though in your example the columns are separated by tab.

Comment: sorry each value corresponding to my key is a list separated by company tickers.  They are separated  by commas.  But in my  output to excel file, thats the format it gets outputted which is weird.  I tried your method but im getting ',' as a column as well which is not what i want